# Handling synchronization with Spotify API fetch requests in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, synchronization, fetch-api

I'm writing a function to get all the music genres provided by Spotify API ([here the documentation](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/get-recommendation-genres)), but i'm facing synchronization issues with fetches.

A brief explanation on how Spotify API work:

To fetch data from Spotify you need to have an "access_token" obtained by a specific fetch ([Request an Access Token](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/tutorials/getting-started)), the token lasts 1 hour. Expired that, you need to regenerate it.

So, I though that every time i'm doing the fetch on the genres, i test the response from spotify, if it says that token is expired, I ask for regeneration and repeat the fetch on genres.
I'm facing problem with synchronization between the 2 functions i wrote below.

I chose to save the sessionToken in the localStorage.

```
function getToken() {
    if (localStorage.getItem("sessionToken") == null) {
        fetch(url, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                Authorization: "Basic " + btoa(`${clientId}:${clientSecret}`),
                "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            },
            body: new URLSearchParams({ grant_type: "client_credentials" }),
         })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((tokenResponse) => {
                localStorage.setItem("sessionToken", tokenResponse.access_token);
            })
    }
}
```

```
function getGenres() {
            let sessionToken = localStorage.getItem("sessionToken");
            fetch(`${BASE}/recommendations/available-genre-seeds`, {
                method: "GET",
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    Authorization: "Bearer " + sessionToken,
                },
             })
                .then(response => {
                    if (!response.ok) {
                        response.json()
                            .then(data => {
                                if (data.error.status == 401) {
                                    localStorage.removeItem("sessionToken");
                                    getToken();
                                    getGenres();
                                }
                            });
                    }
                    else {
                        response.json().then(genres => showGenres(genres));
                    }
                });
}
```

Certainly the problem is in the synchronization between "getToken()" followed by "getGenres()".

Can you kindly give me a hint?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you're facing with synchronization between the `getToken` and `getGenres` functions is because both functions are asynchronous, and the subsequent calls to getGenres after token regeneration are not waiting for the new token to be retrieved.

Here is the updated code using `async`

```
async function getToken() {
  if (localStorage.getItem("sessionToken") == null) {
    const response = await fetch(url, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Authorization: "Basic " + btoa(`${clientId}:${clientSecret}`),
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      },
      body: new URLSearchParams({ grant_type: "client_credentials" }),
    });
    const tokenResponse = await response.json();
    localStorage.setItem("sessionToken", tokenResponse.access_token);
  }
}

async function getGenres() {
  let sessionToken = localStorage.getItem("sessionToken");
  const response = await fetch(`${BASE}/recommendations/available-genre-seeds`, {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Authorization: "Bearer " + sessionToken,
    },
  });
  if (!response.ok) {
    const errorData = await response.json();
    if (errorData.error.status == 401) {
      localStorage.removeItem("sessionToken");
      await getToken();
      await getGenres();
    }
  } else {
    const genres = await response.json();
    showGenres(genres);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Raymond, your solution is what I was trying to achieve. 
Is it possible to get the same result without using await but just with chaining the results of the Promises (I mean with .then())?